# Font Awesome - не отображаются иконки в контенте, загруженном через ajax

Tags: шрифты, css, javascript

Я так понимаю, что все дело в Javascript'e, т.к. если, например, я вставляю код иконки `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` непосредственно в html код страницы, то иконка отображается, но если я хочу вставить какой-нибудь элемент в страницу при помощи javascript'a, то иконка не отображается (смотрю в отладчике, код иконки указан правильно).

Может, как-то нужно инициализировать отрисовку иконок при вставке? Проверяю в хроме.

**Обновление**

Вставляю так:

```
$('#showUploadFiles').append('<br><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o"></i>' + json.zip[i]);
```

Буду очень благодарен, если укажете на мою ошибку!

Comment: Вы как-то неправильно вставляете, хром все прекрасно перерисовывает при изменениях в DOM.

Comment: Возможно. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: попробуйте создать минимальную страницу, на которой повторяется ваша проблема, лучше на jsfiddle.net и дайте в вопросе на нее ссылку - так будет проще найти решение